# Use amp-analytics with amp-sidebar

Tags: amp-html

For example if I want to track if the sidebar has been opened or closed. 
I'm looking for documentation and examples regarding this, so far only found a brief mention in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4508?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container .

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using visibility trigger?

```
"triggers": {
    "trigger name": {
        "on": "visible",
        "selector": "#sidebar_id",
        ....
    }
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use click trigger in amp analytics : https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics#click-trigger

```
    {
  "requests": {
    "pageview": "https://example.com/page",
    "event": "https://example.com/page?category=${eventCategory}&action=${eventAction}"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    },
   "trackClick": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": ".header",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "clickEvent",
        "eventAction": "amp-sidebar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Set selector which is your amp-sidebar selector.
In requests.event there are two variables "eventCategory" and "eventAction" which you can set from the event trigger in "vars" section. JSON named "trackClick" is about how to set the event and it's variables. "requst":"event" means event URL will be called. "on":"click" define click event. "selector" is the html selector on which you want to track click event."vars" will replace variables in event URL when a particular event is fired.